# How to fix "'g++' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Tags: g++, cygwin, clion

I recently downloaded CLion onto my Windows machine. I have cygwin64 installed with g++-gcc, make, cmake, and gdb. It is selected under the toolchain tab as my default environment.

I have looked at the system variable section within "Environment Variables" but perhaps I am not indicating the correct path(s).

```
C:\Users\kdagh\CLionProjects
```

I should be able to compile with g++ but only receive the error:

```
'g++' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: `perhaps I am not indicating the correct path(s)` Maybe you could check this first ? What path did you add ? Is it correct ? If you can find g++.exe there, then the problem lies elsewhere (but I doubt it).

Comment: Did you add the cygwin64 `bin` folder to your `Path` environment variable also? This is the folder that contains the `g++` executable, is it not?

Comment: Yes, I have added C:\cygwin64\bin to the Path system variable.

Comment: Nevermind, I had to put the C:\cygwin64\bin into the Path ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE. I was placing C:\cygwin64\bin into SYSTEM VARIABLES. Thank you for the assistance!